# Слайдер Изоброжений Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slider

Как сделать Слайдер изображений.  Типа слайдера в Плеймаркете (Где скриншоты и картинки приложения). Есть ли какие то статьи и если вы делали такое что вы использовали?

Comment: Вам нужен ViewPager

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  ViewPager нужен чтобы пальцем переводить. В Плеймаркете там разве не тупо HorizantalScrollView?

Comment: Скорее всего там тогда RecyclerView горизонтальный. HorizantalScrollView плох тем, что всё сразу в память грузит, что к OutOfMemory приводит если картинок много.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Часто вижу эту ошибку OutOfMemory. Может быть изза проста ScrolView и RecyclerView вертикально используется?

Comment: Если нужно показывать по одной картинке на вьюхе, то ViewPager , если несколько, то RecyclerView c горизонтальным LinearLayoutManager'ом.